# Access to methods and properties for classes with overloaded index reference

Tags: matlab, operator-overloading

I want to overload the indexing via `()` and `{}` for one of my MATLAB classes. This is possible by implementing [`subsref`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/code-patterns-for-subsref-and-subsasgn-methods.html) for that class, and it works fine.

However, I also want to keep the default behaviour of indexing via `.` (i.e. access to methods and properties) for this class. I tried using the following code:

```
function x = subsref(this, S)
    if strcmp(S(1).type, '{}')
        % My own implementation here
    elseif strcmp(S(1).type, '()')
        % My own implementation here
    elseif strcmp(S(1).type, '.')
        x = builtin('subsref', this, S);
    else
        error('Unknown index variant.');
end
```

However, this does not work because I do not know a priori how many output arguments the call to `builtin('subsref', this, S)` will return. In particular, a method of my class might return a variable number of arguments, with the number of output arguments depending on the number and values of its input arguments. A [MATLAB example for `subsref`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/f3-28024.html#f3-62469) (broken link) notes:

> When you implement a `subsref` method for a class, you must implement all subscripted reference explicitly [...]

Is this really the only possible solution? For complex methods this basically means duplicating a lot of the logic. This is definitely not maintainable in my case (large classes with a lot of methods and properties).

Note: I know that this is all about syntactic sugar and that I can always use standard method calls instead of overloading `()` and `{}`.

Comment: Overloading subsref is almost never a good idea. You will have more headaches then you can anticipate. If you can describe why you are trying to overload subsref and the problem you are trying to address, somebody can probably suggest a better solution than this approach.

Comment: @Kavka: Operator overloading in general is a difficult topic, and there have been long debates about its pros and cons. In my case, I'm writing a list-like object for which indexing via `()` and `{}` are natural extensions. As I said in my original post, overloading operators is usually about syntactic sugar, and the same could be achieved with ordinary methods/properties. Nevertheless, overloaded operators _can_ make the code shorter and clearer if they are implemented well.

Comment: My two cents: for Matlab in particular, while subsasgn and subsref are fussy (even for operator overloading mechanisms), they're worth it in some cases because indexing is so idiomatic in Matlab. Especially if you're doing nested indexing. And it's pretty much required for polymorphic code that uses indexing. I've only done it for a handful of classes (maybe 1% of them), but I use those overriden operators *all* the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a partial fix, I think you can use nargout to defer to the caller, which will usually be in a position to know. Any function that's capturing multiple outputs must know at the time of the call how many it's capturing.

This won't let you display multiple argouts at the command line, but should work as long as you're as you're capturing the returned values, as in most code.

```
function varargout = subsref(this, S)
   switch S(1).type
      ...
      case '.'
         varargout = cell(1, nargout);
         if nargout == 0
             builtin('subsref', this, S);
         else
             [varargout{:}] = builtin('subsref', this, S);
         end
   end
end
```

Caveat emptor: this code is not tested, and there's a bunch of finicky edge cases inside the subsref/subsasgn stuff.

Comment: A good idea. The error messages will probably be confusing if the caller provides the wrong number of arguments (since they'll get an error in `subsref`, not in the method they are thinking they're calling), but I guess you have to live with that if you overload operators.